# Get img thumbnails from liveleak?

Tags: youtube, thumbnails

I want to get a thumbnail image for videos from liveleak.com.

When getting images from Youtube I just do like this:

http://img.youtube.com/vi/HwP5NG-3e8I/2.jpg

Any idea how to do for liveleak.com?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there does not appear to be an easily standardized URL like youtube has, but if you can make a call to the video page, you can scrape out the image fairly easily. There's a `<script>` tag on the page that makes a call to a `jwplayer` function. This function is initialized with an object that has an `image` property. You can use this value as the thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

It will still require scraping the page bu the meta og:image tag in the header also points to the thumbnail image.